# Create nicely designed resumé from info in database

Tags: mysql, css, pdf

I designed a nice resumé template in Sketch and now I want to make it available to use it for the users of a site.
The data will be stored in MySql database and the design should be modular depending on the information.
What is the best way of doing it? I though of replicating the design in CSS3 and then converting it with some of this scripts [fpdf](http://www.fpdf.org/) or [mpdf](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php) but I don't thing that it's the easiest way of doing it.
What do you think?
Thanks!

An example of the resumé is the following:

[image: Example of resumé]

Answer (score 1):

If it's a set template/pattern I'd approach it like each segment as an object with a varying number of attributes based on data it returns from the mysql call.

IE when you pull the data from your table and start looping through a person's skills you can add that to the SKILLS object. Same for the Experience, etc etc.

Since this would essentially be like Parent Child nodes you could also do it with XML but the approach is really up to you.

You could then easily output the constructed resume as HTML (so your users on the site can see it live and may make changes, and then use a converter to convert to PDF (alots of languages have libraries to do just that). Most modern browsers can also already convert HTML pages to PDF too nowadays so you could also give them instructions on how to do that.

Just my two cents,

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks for the quick answer! and what do you think about styling? do you think that it will be a problem for the converters?

Comment: Most converters should be able to handle CSS but I may not be the most familiar with the one you choose so that's something I'd suggest looking into when you're picking out one. You might be able to find some suggestions[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391005/convert-html-css-to-pdf-with-php